# Meet other Mechanics

Tags: discussion

On Travel we have [a Meta post where users update their location on the globe](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1603/meet-other-travel-se-members?s=1%7C2.8061). I think it might be useful to port this idea on Mechanics too since meeting people is always an enriching experience. Moreover knowing where people are can help in [organising site-wide events](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1612/would-you-like-to-hang-out-with-fellow-members-at-some-car-related-event)

Comment: Similar question....http://meta.mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/1612/would-you-like-to-hang-out-with-fellow-members-at-some-car-related-event

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Africa**

**Asia**

- India: [Anarach](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/users/10373/anarach)

**Europe**

- France

  - Anywhere: [JoErNanO](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/users/13657/joernano)
- Spain

  - Mallorca: [EChan42](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/16187/echan42)
- UK

  - Central Scotland: [Rory Alsop](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/users/37/rory-alsop)
  - Southern England: [Nick C](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/users/373/nick-c)
  - North East England: [Steve Matthews](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/users/10927/steve-matthews)

**North America**

- Canada

  - Ontario: [Jonathan Musso](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/users/2899/jonathan-musso)
- USA

  - Stafford, Virginia: [Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/users/4152/p%E1%B4%80%E1%B4%9C%CA%9Fs%E1%B4%9B%E1%B4%87%CA%802)
  - Phoenix, Arizona: [Ducatikiller](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/users/9164/ducatikiller)
  - Syracuse, New York: [Ben](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/users/14393/ben)
  - Dallas, Texas: [JPhi1618](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/users/12030/jphi1618), [Moab](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/users/16882/moab)
  - Baltimore, Maryland: [RPMerf](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/users/10147/rpmerf)
  - Las Vegas, Nevada: [Zipzit](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/users/7551/zipzit)

**Oceania**

- Australia

  - Western Australia: [AaronLavers](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/users/15923/aaron-lavers)

**South America**

**The Middle East**

- Qatar: [Zaid](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/users/675/zaid)

**Other**